# Combine models to get cohesive data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm writing app in witch I store data in separate models. Now I need to combine this data to use it.

**The problem**

I have three models:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    ...

class Contacts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
    contact_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="contact_user")

class UserPhoto(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=220)
```

How can I get the current user contacts with their names and pictures like this (serialized)

```
{
 {
   "contact_user":"1",
   "first_name":"Mark ",
   "url":first picture that corresponds to contact_user id
 },
 {
   "contact_user":"2",
   "first_name":"The Rock",
   "url":first picture that corresponds to contact_user id
 }
}
```

Now I'm querying the *Contacts* model to get all contacts_user id's that he has connection to.

```
class MatchesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Contacts
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1

class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ContactsSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Contacts.objects.filter(user__id=self.request.user.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you need to is to serialize the `Contacts` queryset to include the related `User` and `UserPhoto` objects for each contact.

Try to create a custom serializer for the `Contacts` model so:

```py
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact_user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_contact_user(self, obj):
        user = obj.contact_user
        photo = user.userphoto_set.first()
        return {
            "id": user.id,
            "first_name": user.first_name,
            "url": photo.url if photo else None
        }

    class Meta:
        model = Contacts
        fields = ("contact_user",)
```

Then, modify the `ContactViewSet` to use this newly created serializer so:

```py
class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Contacts.objects.filter(user__id=self.request.user.id)
```

> **Note:** Generally, Django models don't require `s` to be added as suffix since it is by default added, so it is better to modify it as `Contact` from `Contacts`.